# Spring java -rounded corner not working in ie

Tags: javascript, css

I used the following steps

Step1: put pie.htc in  Webcontent/css/pie.htc folder

Step2:add the following codes in my .css file

```
border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
behavior: url(/css/PIE.htc);
```

Please any one help me as sap and the rounded corners working in chrome and firefox

Comment: *sidenote:* You can short code your `border-radius` to `border-radius: 5px;`

Answer (score 1):

You should use vendor-specific prefix in CSS :

```
border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
```

( if you just want to work it in Firefox and Chrome )

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius